# pg_dump ignoring schema specified with -n

Tags: postgresql

I am using pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4.

I have a database with two different schemas that have identical table names.

```
- mydatabase
    - schema_a
        - mytable
        - someothertable
    - schema_b
        - mytable
        - another table
```

I want to copy both schema_a.mytable and schema_b.mytable from orig_host to new_host.  I log into new_host and type:

```
% psql -c "drop schema schema_a cascade" mydatabase
% psql -c "create schema schema_a" musicbrainz_db
% pg_dump -h orig_host -n schema_a -t mytable mydatabase | psql mydatabase
```

No problem, but when I do the same for schema_b, I get conflicts:

```
% psql -c "drop schema schema_b cascade" mydatabase
% psql -c "create schema schema_b" musicbrainz_db
% pg_dump -h orig_host -n schema_b -t mytable mydatabase | psql mydatabase

ERROR:  relation "artist" already exists
```

I confirm by dumping this last command to a file that it is setting the search path to schema_a, which causes the failure.  It does seem to work if I do

% pg_dump -h orig_host -t schema_b.mytable mydatabase | psql mydatabase

But shouldn't the -n switch work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html) -

> The -n and -N switches have no effect when -t is used, because tables selected by -t will be dumped regardless of those switches, and non-table objects will not be dumped.

You might have schema_a in your search_path, which is why the first command works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SQL produced. I believe what you should see is:

1. Everything in schema_a
2. All tables named *.mytable

That is, the options are additive.

I'm guessing the intent is that schema S might well depend on one or two other tables so you can dump them all together.